# Lambda body isn’t executed unless corresponding method is invoked

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I am learning about Java Lambdas and I asked myself is it always required to call a abstract method of functional interface if I want to use the lambda here?

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface A {
    public void somefunction();
}

@FunctionalInterface
public interface B extends A {

}

public class testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = () -> System.out.println("MyText");

        b.somefunction();   //Why do I need to call somefunction()
    }
}
```

If I don't write `b.somefunction();` I don't get any output even though the compiler does not give an error.

I don't pass any value to the method so why do I need to call the abstract method?

Is there anyway to skip the abstract method call? If my case was to **add** or perform some *calculations*, then I can understand that I need to pass some values in method, but in the above scenario I am just printing the value.

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you want to have happen what's behind the method call, you have to perform the method call.

Comment: when i am erasing `b.somefunction()` then my output is not coming.

Comment: "If i dont write b.somefunction(); the output is not coming, even compiler is not giving error." Well no, it wouldn't. You're creating an implementation of `B`, but you're never executing the method that would lead to `System.out.println("MyText")` being executed. What do you *believe* the first line of your `main` method does? I suspect that's where you're confused at the moment. Imagine you were using an anonymous inner class instead of a lambda expression - would you expect any output then, just by creating an object?

Comment: @JonSkeet , i really did not got your point, please explain a more bit. I am executing main and in main only my system.out is there, so why i need to execute back that abstract method??

Comment: On a certain abstraction level, defining an object via a lambda is a bit like having a method which does the code inside. Unless you call it, it won't do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A functional interface serves to provide a way

1. to define what is to be performed on a given call and
2. to define *when* it is to be called.

Normally, you'd define a "lambda object" as you did and then pass it to somewhere else to tell what to do under a certain circumstance. If you want to see it this way, it is a kind of callback.

The entity where you pass this object calls/uses it when it sees time to do so, or you do it yourself, as you do it in your example.

Comment: anyway around when i can skip the abstract function call?

Comment: @CommonMan No, if you want to execute it, you need to call it.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the output to print when your program runs, write:

```
public class testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("MyText");
    }
}
```

If you want the output to print when some other function runs, then you might use a lambda:

```
class Testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        runn(() -> System.out.println("MyText"), 10);
    }
    static runn(Runnable task, int times) {
        for (int i = 0; i < times; ++i) {
            task.run();
        }
    }
}
```

Lambdas exist to make it easy to specify a function whose execution you want to delegate to another entity. When the lambda is invoked, its arguments, and the treatment of its result are up to someone else.